# Adding List Data to a Text File

Tags: c#, list, foreach, notepad

I am trying to save the list of data from C# code to a text file. It throws an error at `foreach` stating that list cannot be converted to string. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

I have to Run Application only on .Net Framework 3.5

```
IList<FolderDetails> ListToCheck;

 using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\LogFile.txt"))
 {
     foreach (string line in ListToCheck)
     {                       
         file.WriteLine(line);                        
     }
}
public class FolderDetails
{
    public string PropertyGroupName { get; set; }
    public string ProjFiles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the full code with the question.

Comment: You need to include a [*complete* example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry its a type it is ListToCheck and not folderListToCheck.

Comment: Each element of `ListToCheck` is a `FolderDetails` not a `string`.  That's a problem.

Comment: What type of object is `FolderDetails` ?

Comment: @Kaz OP included that class in the code.  It is a type.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: He added it just now.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Ah, so he did....yeah, that's the problem right there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Examine this code:

```
IList<FolderDetails> ListToCheck;

using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\LogFile.txt"))
{
    foreach (string line in ListToCheck)
```

You say ListToCheck is a list of objects of type FolderDetail, but in

```
foreach (string line in ListToCheck)
```

you try to assert that the type is string instead.

Try something like

```
foreach (FolderDetail line in ListToCheck)
{
    file.WriteLine(line.SomeAppropriatePropertyOfFolderDetail);
```

Answer (score 2):

Rework it this way...

Add a ToString() override to your class:

```
private class FolderDetails
{
    public string PropertyGroupName { get; set; }
    public string ProjFiles { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}:{1}", this.PropertyGroupName, this.ProjFiles);
    }
}
```

Then output like this:

```
List<FolderDetails> foldersListToCheck = GetFolderDetails();
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\LogFile.txt", foldersListToCheck.Select(f => f.ToString()));
```

Comment: That won't compile, will it?  The WriteAllLines method requires a collection of strings.  Having a ToString method doesn't make an object into a string.

Comment: AllLines is part of .Net framework 3.5+. My situation is I have to use this code in sharepoint 2010 app which supports 3.5 only.

Comment: The OP's original StreamWriter.WriteLine has an overload that accepts Object, so that overload will automatically call ToString() to get the appropriate representation.

Answer (score 1):

```
IList<FolderDetails> ListToCheck;

 using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\LogFile.txt"))
 {
     foreach (string line in ListToCheck)
     {                       
         file.WriteLine(line);                        
     }
}
```

In the above code ListToCheck is not a list of strings and it is not initialized